# Change value pointed to by strstr(); C

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program to find and replace some text in a string at the moment I'm trying to change `"hello how are you"` to `"hello bow are you"` as a test.

So firstly I find the `"how"` by using `char *substring = strstr(mystring, newstr);`
which returns a pointer to `"(this position)how are you"` now I have no idea how to change the next 3 letters. I can `strlen(newstr)` for the length of the string I'm replacing `"how"` with but I can't find a way to change mystring starting from the pointer newstr.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker How is this question too broad? It is a reasonable and easy to understand beginner's question.

Comment: @JohnKugelman "If there's anything I can read up on I'd be thrilled." and "I'm trying to make a program, but I'm not actually showing you my code in the entirety that you'd need to see where the bug is; could you give me something to read?"

Comment: Sorry the question was hard to understand! Its been solved already so being on hold doesnt matter anyhow.

Comment: B Hili The post and answers are not just about you, but also making a useful resource for others - it does matter.

Comment: but the post has been answered so if someone has the same issue it's here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the first character by subscripting the substring.

```
substring[0] = 'b';
```

If you want to replace multiple characters, try a loop, or use memcpy. Don't use strcpy: you don't want the NUL terminator to be copied.

```
memcpy(substring, "how", 3);
```

Comment: Memcpy is a more elegant solution than mine thank you for bringing my attention to it.

Answer (score -2):

`*substring = 'b';` as posted by user EOF my solution was as so

```
for (int x = 0; x < strlen(newstring); x++){
    *substring++ = newstring[x];
}
```

Comment: If you want to replace multiple characters in sequence, change the line to `*substring++ = newstring[x];`